# AWS API Gateway with Python-EVE "where" not working in deployed API

Tags: api, amazon-web-services, aws-api-gateway, eve

I have a [Python-eve](http://python-eve.org) public API, and we can query it in the way:

> https://my-api.com/collections?where={"name":"peter"}

I want to create an API Gateway to proxy the same URL endpoint, in the way:

https://my-api-amazon-gateway.com/prod/collections?where={"name":"peter"}

What I did:

1. I create a new API Gateway, with a new resource "collections", and a "GET" method for this resource.
2. In the *collections - GET - Method Execution*, in Method Request:

   - in *URL Query String Parameters*, I add one with name "where"
   - in *HTTP Request Headers*, I add one with name "Content-Type"
3. In the "collections - GET - Method Execution", in "Integration Request"

   - in *URL Query String Parameters* I have name "where" and Mapped from "method.request.querystring.where"
   - in *HTTP Headers*, I add one item "Content-Type" with Mapped from "method.request.header.Content-Type"

If I go to *Method Test*, and I put `{"name":"peter"}` as *where Query Strings*, and `application/json` as *Header content-type*, all works very nice.

If I deploy the API and try same endpoint in the deployed API, it is not working:

> https://my-api-amazon-gateway.com/prod/collections?where={"name":"peter"}

It returns an error **400 Bad Request**. Nothing is logged in CloudWatch.

If I try to hit

> https://my-api-amazon-gateway.com/prod/collections?where=test

Then all work as It should, I get **HTTP 200 OK**, with the Python-eve error `The browser (or proxy) sent a request that this server could not understand.`
that is the same result than If I try to hit

> https://my-api.com/collections?where=test

So, for a reason that I do not know, the test works, but the deployed API Gateway it is not working when the query string is an object.

Any clue about this?

Thank you very much!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You will need to URL encode the parameter. The reason it works when testing via Method Test is because it takes care of encoding the parameters.

Instead of,
    **https://my-api-amazon-gateway.com/prod/collections?where={"name":"peter"}**

Try it with,
    **https://my-api-amazon-gateway.com/prod/collections?where=%7B%22name%22%3A%22peter%22%7D**

Hope this helps

Comment: how to handle this in react.js?